# multiplex the flow in flume into several channels

Tags: flume-ng

I want to multiplex the flow in flume into several channels based on the file name. How can it done?  I used spool directory source. I used a channel selector. It should multiply the flow by the file name in event header.

I have lot of files named as CA,AZ,CA2,AZ2,....so on.CA files shuold write to the /flume_sink/CA directory, AZ files shuold write to the /flume_sink/AZ and KT is the default directory.Following code is used. But it didn't do multiplexing. It is doing replication.

Whats wrong with the configuration?

```
agent1.sinks=hdfs-sink1_1 hdfs-sink1_2 hdfs-sink1_3
agent1.sources=source1_1
agent1.channels=fileChannel1_1 fileChannel1_2 fileChannel1_3

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.type=file
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.capacity=200000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.transactionCapacity=1000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/alpha/001
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.dataDirs=/home/Flume/alpha_data
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.checkpointOnClose=true
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.dataOnClose=true


agent1.sources.source1_1.type=spooldir
agent1.sources.source1_1.spoolDir=/home/ABC/
agent1.sources.source1_1.recursiveDirectorySearch=true
#agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeader=true
#agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeaderKey=file
agent1.sources.source1_1.fileSuffix=.COMPLETED
agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeader = true
agent1.sources.source1_1.basenameHeaderKey = basename

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.type=hdfs
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/CA
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.batchSize=1000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollSize=268435456
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollInterval=0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollCount=50000000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false


agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.type=file
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.capacity=200000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.transactionCapacity=1000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/beta/001
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.dataDirs=/home/Flume/beta_data
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.checkpointOnClose=true
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_2.dataOnClose=true



agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.type=hdfs
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/AZ
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.batchSize=1000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollSize=268435456
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollInterval=0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.rollCount=50000000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false

agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.type=file
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.capacity=200000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.transactionCapacity=10
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.checkpointDir=/home/Flume/gamma/001
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.dataDirs=/home/Flume/gamma_data
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.checkpointOnClose=true
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_3.dataOnClose=true


agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.type=hdfs
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.path=hdfs://10.44.209.44:9000/flume_sink/KT
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.batchSize=1000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.rollSize=268435456
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.rollInterval=0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.rollCount=50000000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=false


agent1.sources.source1_1.channels=fileChannel1_1 fileChannel1_2 fileChannel1_3

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.channel=fileChannel1_1
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_2.channel=fileChannel1_2
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_3.channel=fileChannel1_3


agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.type=replicating
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=basename
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.CA=fileChannel1_1
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.mapping.AZ=fileChannel1_2
agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.default=fileChannel1_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fileHeader and fileHeaderKey properties in spooling directory source
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source

Comment: I used fileHeaderKey anf fileHeader properties as follows. agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeader=true agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeaderKey=file Then what should be the agent1.sources.source1_1.selector.header=???